# Link on old (but high PageRank) blog post broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, blog

I googled for the terms `stackoverflow get email for a tag` and the top hit was [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/).

Unfortunately, the link for [Tag Sets page on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/popular) leads to a `404`. I believe it should be updated to [this](https://stackexchange.com/tagsets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know.

I've updated the blog post with the correct link.

Comment: That link still appears to be broken.

Comment: Might have regressed when we moved blog platforms. Fixed... again...